# OwlCarousel control element wrong positioning after content height change

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have an OwlCarousel below an accordion. The problem now is when i collapse an accordion, then the slider move down but the control elements not.

When i resize the window, then it calculate it right again. It seems to be a css issue but i didn't figured out what exactly. The parent element has a `relative` definition so it should it be relative to it.

Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7jvw87a/4/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'position: initial' to owl controls.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer -SO reviews

Comment: I don't know exactly how you mean it. could you show me on jsfiddle?